# Can you run under a "shade" to protect yourself from the "rain"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it correct to say that you run under a **shade** to protect yourself from the **rain**? Or is "shade" only applicable for protecting yourself from the sun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word, **" To Shade"** usually refers to the use of the shadow of an object to protect oneself from direct sunlight. I don't think it could be used to describe protection from rain. Perhaps you meant, **"Cover"**? You could say, for example,

> "I ran to find cover from the rain"

But otherwise, **"Shade"** should only be used when referring to protection from sunlight.